# Wall calendar with monthly background and moon days (if possible)

Tags: calendar, tikz-calendar

I have been working based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652488/75648) but I can't get the background to change for each month.
The moon feature from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88274/75648) is also not working for this tikz.
There are also some minor changes, so in summary:

- A PNG tiled background should be different for each month.
- Whole month border.
- Include moon phases before the day number  (if possible).
- No vertical lines at the days of the week.
- Horizontal lines for hand writing.
- Rounded corner border around month - year.

Also, how do I change language?

[image: Current and desired result]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a2paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin={1cm}, top= 6cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*\thepage{}
\usepackage{mathabx}
%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\tikzset{
    every weekday/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        black,
        fill=white,
        font=\scshape\bfseries,
        name=weekday-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
        node contents=\%wt
    },
    weekday above/.style={
        draw=none,
        if = {(day of month=1) [days={append after command={
                    node [at={(\tikzlastnode.north west)}, alias=@firstweekday, every weekday]}}]},
        if = {(day of month=2, day of month=3, day of month=4, day of month=5, day of month=6, day of month=7) [
            days={append after command={
                    node [at={(@firstweekday.south west-|\tikzlastnode.south west)}, every weekday]}}]}
    },
    wall calendar/.style={
        week list,
        weekday above,
        day text=,
        day and weekday/.style={
            draw,
            outer sep=+0pt,
            fill=white,
            line width=.12em,
            minimum width=\linewidth/7,
            minimum height=\textheight/7
        },
        day xshift=\linewidth/7,
        day yshift=\textheight/7, %altura da celula
        every day label/.style={
            anchor=north east,
            font=\Huge,
            node contents={\%d=},
            inner sep=.7em
        },
        every day/.append style={
            day and weekday,
            label={[every day label]north east:}
        },
        every weekday/.append style={
            day and weekday,
            inner xsep=0pt,
            minimum height=1.5em
        },
        moon code/.code={
            \edef\listmoons{#1}%
            \def\moons{}%
            \foreach \l in \listmoons {%
                \xappto\moons{if (equals = \pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\l) [day text=\noexpand\moon\%d-]}
            }%
            \tikzset{every day/.append style={\moons}}
        }
    }
}

\newcount\mooncounter
\def\moonreset{\global\mooncounter=-1\relax}
\moonreset

\def\moon{%
    \global\advance\mooncounter by 1\relax%
    \ifcase\mooncounter $\newmoon$%
    \or             $\rightmoon$%
    \or             $\fullmoon$%
    \or             $\leftmoon$\global\mooncounter=-1\relax%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand*{\listofmoons}[1]{%
    \edef\listmoons{#1}%
    \def\moons{}%
    \foreach \l in \listmoons {%
        \xappto\moons{if (equals = 2023-12-\l) [day text=\noexpand\moon\%d-]}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily\LARGE
    
    \centering
    \newcommand*\Year{2023}
    \moonreset
    \foreach \mon in {6,...,12}{% 1,...,12
        \listofmoons{2,6,7,8,9,12,27}
        {\par \fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont\bfseries  {\pgfcalendarmonthname{\mon}} - \Year \par}
        \vspace{2em}
        \tikz\calendar[
        dates=\Year-0\mon-01 to \Year-0\mon-last,
        wall calendar,
        moon code={2,6,7,8,9,12,27}
        ];
        \pagebreak
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: The moon thingy doesn't work because the other answer doesn't use `day text` as it's supposed to be. Language needs babel, translate and calendar in this order, I believe, with the language as an option to the class. I would output the whole page as one TikZ picture which makes it much easier to control the vertical and horizontal spacing instead of using `geometry`. Do you have the dates for the moon phase in a different dataset? You will need to have a list of days per month (or a formula).

Comment: As for the moon, I was hoping to use something like this. https://minkukel.com/en/various/calculating-moon-phase/. As for the TikZ picture, I tried that, and managed to get a background, but still the same for all months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How it works

- It's much easier (for me) to use TikZ to create the whole page instead of using `geometry` and such things.
- A lot of dimensions are controlled via key values in the `/cal` namespace (see `\calset`), this includes

  - the page dimensions,
  - the borders (`border top` is the space between weekdays and the header)
  - the header dimensions (current you need to make sure it is wide enough to fit the longest head).
- The background is done via layers at the end of the picture, a background for each month can be set by `set background = {<month number>}{<TikZ styles>}`.

  You can see two examples for `6` and `7`.
- Translations are provided by the `babel` package and implemented via the `translator` package (this is a feature of the `calendar` utility) which needs to be loaded before TikZ. (This is why I'm using `multi=tikzpicture` instead of `tikz` as a class option since otherwise `standalone` would load `tikz` before we have a change to load `translator` before.)
- The language is given as a class option. Since you didn't specify the language I'm using `ngerman` for this example.
- Since you don't want a background for the days of the week from the previous or next month, I'm using my `ext.calendar-plus` library to be able to use the conditionals `and`, `week of month` and `calendar week of month` (and their `'` variants) to add another day in the appropriate places.

  This is taken from [Full weeks in Tikz Calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660335)
- No vertical lines between the weekdays is done by removing the `draw` option in `every weekday` and just draw a rectangle around them at the end.

#### Todo

- Lines to write on.
- What to do with months that have less than 6 weeks?

  Currently the height of the day boxes doesn't change like in
  [TikZ / calendar: Set the height of a monthly calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653146)

  At the bottom of the page remains empty space which doesn't even have an extra area to write on.
- Moon stuff. (It will be easier to provide the dates instead of calculating them, especially when we're thinking about time zones.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[ngerman,multi=tikzpicture]{standalone}
\usepackage{babel, translator, tikz}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, ext.calendar-plus, patterns.meta}
\newcommand*\cvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/cal/#1}}
\newcommand*\calset{\pgfqkeys{/cal}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add day from week before/.default=, add day from week after/.default=,
  add day from week before/.code={%
    \begingroup % shift whole calendar 7 days in the past
      \advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by -7
      \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
      \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday{\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweek{\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<10 0\fi\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgftransformyshift{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day yshift}}%
      \tikzset{every day from week before/.try,#1}%
      \tikzdaycode
    \endgroup},
  add day from week after/.code={%
    \begingroup % shift whole calendar 7 days in the future
      \advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by +7
      \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
      \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday{\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweek{\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<10 0\fi\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day yshift})}%
      \tikzset{every day from week after/.try,#1}%
      \tikzdaycode
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother
\calset{
  page width/.initial =594mm,
  page height/.initial=420mm,
  border   left/.initial=1cm,
  border  right/.initial=1cm,
  border    top/.initial=1cm,
  border bottom/.initial=1cm,
  weekday height/.initial=1.5em,
  header height/.initial=10em,
  header width/.initial=15em,
  header rounded corners radius/.initial=2em,
  height for calendar/.initial=(\cvo{page height}-\cvo{border top}-\cvo{border bottom}-\cvo{weekday height}-\cvo{header height}),
  @initialize backgrounds/.style={
    /cal/background #1/.style={
      execute at end picture={
        \scoped[on background layer]
          \path[/cal/every background/.try,/cal/background #1/.try]
            ([xshift=(\cvo{border right}),yshift=-(\cvo{header rounded corners radius})]@header.north-|@weekday-6.east)
            rectangle ++ ({-(\cvo{page width})},{-(\cvo{page height})});}}},
  @initialize backgrounds/.list={1,...,12},
  set background/.style 2 args={/cal/background #1/.append style={#2}},
  set background={6}{fill=gray},
  set background={7}{
    preaction={fill=orange!25},
    pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=5mm, line width=.5mm]},
    pattern color=black
  },
}
\tikzset{
  weekday above/.style={
    if = {(day of month=1) [days={append after command={
                node [at={(\tikzlastnode.north west)}, alias=@firstweekday, every weekday]}}]},
    if = {(day of month=2, day of month=3, day of month=4, day of month=5, day of month=6, day of month=7) [
        days={append after command={
                node [at={(@firstweekday.south west-|\tikzlastnode.south west)}, every weekday]}}]}
  },
  wall calendar/.style={
    week list,
    weekday above,
    header text/.store in=\tikzheadertext,
    day code={\node[every day]{};}, % no \tikzdaytext here
    every head/.style={
      minimum width=\cvo{header width},
      minimum height=\cvo{header height}+\cvo{header rounded corners radius},
      rounded corners=\cvo{header rounded corners radius},
      fill=white,
      label={[anchor=south,every head text]below:\tikzheadertext},
      name=@header,
      overlay,
      draw = orange,
      line width=1mm,
    },
    every head text/.style={
      font = \Huge\bfseries,
      above = .5*(\cvo{header rounded corners radius}),
      text depth=+0pt,
    },
    header text=\%mt -- \%y0,
    day and weekday/.style={
      draw,
      outer sep=+0pt,
      fill=white,
      text=black,
      minimum width=(\cvo{page width}-\cvo{border left}-\cvo{border right})/7,
    },
    every day/.style={
      day and weekday,
      name=day-\pgfcalendarcurrentday,
      alias=@day,
      minimum height=\cvo{height for calendar}/6,
      label={[every day label]:},
    },
    day xshift=(\cvo{page width}-\cvo{border left}-\cvo{border right})/7,
    day yshift=\cvo{height for calendar}/6,
    every weekday/.style={
      day and weekday,
      anchor=south west,
      draw=none,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      font=\scshape\bfseries,
      minimum height=\cvo{weekday height},
      name=@weekday-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
      node contents=\%wt,
      style/.expanded={
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday=3
          label={[above=\cvo{border top},every head]above:}\fi},
    },
    every day label/.style={
      anchor=north east,
      label position=north east,
      font=\Huge,
      node contents={\tikzdaytext},
      inner sep=.7em
    },
  }
}
\newcommand*\Year{2023}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\LARGE
\foreach \mon in {6,...,12}{% 1,...,12
  \tikz[
    /cal/background \mon/.try,
    execute at end picture={\draw[overlay] (@weekday-0.south west) rectangle (@weekday-6.north east);}]
    \calendar[
      wall calendar,
      if = {(and = {week of month = 1, calendar week of month = 2}) [add day from week before={day text=}]},
      if = {(and = {week of month'= 1, calendar week of month'= 2}) [add day from week after ={day text=}]},
      dates=\Year-0\mon-01 to \Year-0\mon-last,
    ];
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fantastic! I realized I was running tex 2021, so ext.calendar-plus was not working.
However I can't seem to change the background to a image, the includegraphics generate error. I am sure it must be simple but i'm kind of lost in tikz long manual.

Comment: I have manage to get the result using your `pgfsetupimageaspattern` , found here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103980/tikz-define-pattern-with-reference-to-external-picture